# /dev/sda isn't there

Tags: hard-drive, kubuntu, disk

My laptop runs Kubuntu 17.04, but this problem has started happening even before I upgraded to Zesty.

There are times where I would be working, then suddenly I am unable to save my work (and the software I am working with - Blender 3d - tells me that it is unable to save in a Read-Only file system), Firefox crashes and a small error window pops up telling me "Cannot find the program 'firefox'", and the whole screen goes black.

Similarly, sometimes I will be working in the terminal, and `sudo apt-get` stops working and gives me an Input-Output error.  Sometimes it even says that sudo is not a command.  Then, the screen goes black.

I immediately suspect an error with the hard drive.  So, I went googling, and I found another StackExchange thread that was about how to scan hard drive for issues using smartctl (link [here](https://superuser.com/questions/171195/how-to-check-the-health-of-a-hard-drive)).  I install the smartmontools package, run `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda | less` as suggested, and bam, error message, "`Smartctl open device: /dev/sda failed: No such device`".  I go in and check the /dev directory and sure enough there's not an sda directory at all.  No sdb, no sda1, nothing.

What's wrong? Is my hard drive dying? Can I recover it?  Am I doing something stupid?  I've just switched over from Windows so I may not be understanding something completely or missing something.

Comment: Backup your data NOW! Your drive is probably dying. Use the `journalctl /dev/sda`,`journalctl`, see  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs

Comment: Alternatively, have you vibrated/jarred a cable loose in your laptop?

Comment: @waltinator Oh geez.  Well I haven't dropped my laptop at all in the history of it's existence, so I don't think it's that.  I'll back it up now.

Comment: Totally agree. Get it working, then back it up. Try the obvious first.  Get physical access, even if you have to open the whole case up and check the connections. Could be loose. Could be corroded. I've seen both. In the worst case, if you can't get it working by correcting something like that, you might try taking it out of case, leaving it connected. Obviously you can't do this if the cable isn't long enough. Then put it in a water but thin plastic bag.

Comment: Maybe double bag it. Get all the air out you can and bury it in ice in a bowl, taking care not to let any meltwater or ice in. When it is cold, try again to back it up. Of course, you might try fsck, but, and I may be wrong here (look it up if nobody comments on this) but I don't think fsck can deal with anything that would stop `sudo blkid` from seeing the device. It is just for filesystem corruption, but you might have that issue too. I think failing hardware can lead to filesystem corruption on top of the original hardware problem. Good luck.

Comment: Also of course, shutdown and let your whole system cool for an hour or so. Might work. Good luck. Always backup every time you write important data.